# Help with an if then statement. Apple Remote Desktop and setting Computer Info Field

Tags: bash

This is a great script for network admins. It's able to set the AppleCare expiration date of the computer the script is run on in a computer info field allowing for easy sorting in Apple Remote Desktop. My issue is when a computer has an expired warranty I would like the script to set the info field to "Out of Coverage". The script runs as is and I've commented out the code that I think will be needed to do this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks everyone.

```
#!/bin/bash
# warranty.sh
# Description: looks up Apple warranty info for 
# this computer, or one specified by serial number 

# Based on a script by Scott Russell, IT Support Engineer, 
# University of Notre Dame
# http://www.nd.edu/~srussel2/macintosh/bash/warranty.txt
# Edited to add the ASD Versions by Joseph Chilcote
# Last Modified: 09/16/2010
# Edited 02/10/2011
# Updated support url 
# Added function to write data to plist

## Add function to cycle through a csv file

###############
##  GLOBALS  ##
###############

# make sure you use a full path
PlistLocal=".appwarranty.plist"
WarrantyTempFile="/tmp/warranty.txt"
AsdCheck="/tmp/asdcheck.txt"

if [[ $# == 0 ]] ; then
    SerialNumber=`system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | grep "Serial Number" | grep -v "tray" |  awk -F ': ' {'print $2'} 2>/dev/null`
else
    SerialNumber="${1}"
fi

[[ -n "${SerialNumber}" ]] && WarrantyInfo=`curl -k -s "https://selfsolve.apple.com/warrantyChecker.do?sn=${SerialNumber}&country=USA" | awk '{gsub(/\",\"/,"\n");print}' | awk '{gsub(/\":\"/,":");print}' | sed s/\"\}\)// > ${WarrantyTempFile}`

curl -k -s https://github.com/chilcote/warranty/raw/master/asdcheck -o ${AsdCheck} > /dev/null 2>&1


#################
##  FUNCTIONS  ##
#################

AddPlistString()
{
    # $1 is key name $2 is key value $3 plist location
    # example: AddPlistString warranty_script version1 /Library/ETC/appwarranty.plist
    /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add :"${1}" string \"${2}\"" "${3}"
}

SetPlistString()
{
    # $1 is key name $2 is key value $3 plist location
    # example: SetPlistString warranty_script version2 /Library/ETC/appwarranty.plist
    /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "set :"${1}" \"${2}\"" "${3}"
}

GetWarrantyValue()
{
    grep ^"${1}" ${WarrantyTempFile} | awk -F ':' {'print $2'}
}
GetWarrantyStatus()
{
    grep ^"${1}" ${WarrantyTempFile} | awk -F ':' {'print $2'}
}
GetModelValue()
{
    grep "${1}" ${WarrantyTempFile} | awk -F ':' {'print $2'}
}
GetAsdVers()
{
    #echo "${AsdCheck}" | grep -w "${1}:" | awk {'print $1'}
    grep "${1}:" ${AsdCheck} | awk -F':' {'print $2'}
}

###################
##  CREATE PLIST ##
###################

if [[ ! -e "${PlistLocal}" ]]; then
    AddPlistString warrantyscript version1 "${PlistLocal}"
    for i in purchasedate warrantyexpires warrantystatus modeltype asd
    do
    AddPlistString $i unknown "${PlistLocal}"
    done
fi

###################
##  APPLICATION  ##
###################

echo "$(date) ... Checking warranty status"
InvalidSerial=`grep "wc.check.err.usr.pd04.invalidserialnumber" "${WarrantyTempFile}"`

###
# this is the part I'm struggling with
#
###
#
#   WarrantyStatus=`GetWarrantyStatus HW_SUPPORT_COV_SHORT`
#   echo "WarrantyStatus   ==  ${WarrantyStatus}"
#   SetPlistString warrantystatus "${WarrantyStatus}" "${PlistLocal}"
#
###
# if above is equal to "Out of Coverage" then 
# /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -configure -computerinfo -set4 -4 "Out of Coverage"
# and stop
# Else do below
###

if [[ -e "${WarrantyTempFile}" && -z "${InvalidSerial}" ]] ; then

    WarrantyExpires=`GetWarrantyValue HW_END_DATE`
    echo "WarrantyExpires  ==  ${WarrantyExpires}"
    SetPlistString warrantyexpires "${WarrantyExpires}" "${PlistLocal}"

else
    if [[ -z "${SerialNumber}" ]]; then 
        echo "     No serial number was found."
        SetPlistString warrantystatus "Serial Not Found: ${SerialNumber}" "${PlistLocal}"
    fi
    if [[ -n "${InvalidSerial}" ]]; then
        echo "     Warranty information was not found for ${SerialNumber}."
        SetPlistString warrantystatus "Serial Invalid: ${SerialNumber}" "${PlistLocal}"
    fi
fi

####################################
##  MONTH CONVERSION & ARD ENTRY  ##
####################################

expdate=`date -j -f "%B %d, %Y" "${WarrantyExpires}" "+%Y-%m-%d"`
/System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -configure -computerinfo -set4 -4 "$expdate"

exit 0
```

Comment: Rusty's comment: "David, Glenn has answered your question and adding that code will work. I'd also consider adding this into the code with a variable that would de/activate the kickstart. Follow the development here: https://github.com/rustymyers/warranty"

Answer (score 2):

Seems pretty straightforward. I assume the `WarrantyStatus` variable is the thing that's supposed to hold this string:

```
if [[ "$WarrantyStatus" = "Out of Coverage" ]]; then
   .../kickstart -configure -computerinfo -set4 -4 "$WarrantyStatus"
   exit
fi
```

Comment: but the script will just continue and try to find the date even though its out of coverage and therefore error out. If it finds your statement to be true then the script needs to stop. If it finds your statement to be false then it needs to continue. Thanks for the help Glenn.

Comment: The `exit` statement will stop the script. Do you have another idea about what "stop" is supposed to mean?